# Verify the hypothesis of de l'Hopital

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I have to prove the hierarchy of infinite applying de l'hopital theorem to the following limit.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log{x}}{x^{\alpha}}\,\,\,\, , \alpha>0$$
To apply de l'Hopital I have to verify:

1. $\log{x}$ and $x^{\alpha}$ are differentiable in a unbounded interval $E$.
2. $(x^{\alpha})'\neq 0$ in $E$.

In my case I have that $\log{x}$ and $x^{\alpha}$ surely are differentiable in $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$, but what is my $E$ here? I have to take $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ separately for the right and left limit?

Comment: You are taking the limit $x \to \infty$. So surely $E$ must be the one which is unbounded above?

Comment: do you mean that I can take $E=(-\infty,0)$ or also $E=(0,infty)$?

Comment: Which one of those choices is unbounded above?

Comment: the second! Ok very thanks! Another question...if I have $x\to x_0$ the two function must be derivable in a right or left neighbourhood of $x_0$? For instance if I have the limit for $x\to \pi/2$ my functions must be differentiable for instance in $(0,\pi/2)$ and also in $(\pi/2,\pi)$?

Comment: @ayeayemaung can you help me in understanding how work in case of $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

You can let $E\colon =(0,\infty)$. More specifically, here is how I would argue.

First, note that $f(x)=\operatorname{log}(x)$ and $g(x)=x^\alpha$ are differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Additionally, since $\alpha>0$ holds, we have

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^\alpha=\infty= \lim_{x \to \infty}\operatorname{log}(x).$$

Moreover, for all $x\in (0,\infty)$ the derivative of $g$ at $x$ is non-zero, i.e.

$$g'(x)=\alpha\cdot x^{\alpha-1}\neq 0.$$

Since the following limit exists $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\frac{1}{\alpha}\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x^\alpha}=0,$$
it follows from l'Hospital's rule that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0.$$